# How to take whole Html /xhtml file in single string to write?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, string, parsing

I am new in c# , 
i just want to know is it possible to take whole html document in a single string.
i even want to write it in another file.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Note that for most uses, it's likely more efficient to deal with smaller pieces, so the entire file doesn't have to be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myhtmlfiles\index.html");

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\someotherfile.html", html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string readPath= "D:\\Read.html";
string writePath= "D:\\write.html";

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readPath);
string html = sr.ReadToEnd();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath);
sw.WriteLine(html);
```

or

```
 string path = "D:\\Read.html";
 string path1 = "D:\\write.html";

 html=ReadAllText(path);
 File.WriteAllText(path1, html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure no problem. `string foo = file.ReadToEnd()`.